# uncheck selected checkbox when one of the checkbox option has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I have 2 groups of checkbox options on same page. below is the code.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<label class="checkbox-inline"> 
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerRace1}"  th:value="1"  th:text="borrower1" />
 </label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12">
 <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
 <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerRace1}"  th:value="2"  th:text="borrower2" />
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
  <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
   <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerRace1}"  th:value="3"  th:text="borrower3" />
       </label>
   </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
          <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerRace1}"  th:value="4" th:text="borrower4" />
        </label>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-12">
              <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
  <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerEthnicity1}"  th:value="1" th:text="Ethnicity1" />
           </label>
        </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12">
         <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
         <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerEthnicity2}"  th:value="2" th:text="Ethnicity2" />
      </label>
          </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
 <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerEthnicity3}"  th:value="3"  th:text="Ethnicity3" />
</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
<label class="checkbox-inline"> 
 <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerEthnicity4}"  th:value="4" th:text="Ethnicity4" />
   </label>
    </div>
```

Now,

- User can select first 3 check boxes but clicking the 4th (last) one should 
  select the 4th (last) one and deselect all other of the set. Same should 
  happen for all checkbox sets.
- Example : User can select A,B,C checkbox at a same time but when he checks D 
  all the above selected checkboxes should get unselected. Similarly for E,F,G 
  and H. I hope I am clear now.

Please help me on this. I hope I am clear, if not please do let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code section should work according to your requirement

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.checkbox1').on('click', function() {    
   var last_chekbox1 = $('.checkbox1:last');   
   if (last_chekbox1.is(':checked')) {     
     $('.checkbox1').prop('checked', false);
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }    
  });
  $('.checkbox2').on('click', function(e) {
   var last_chekbox2 = $('.checkbox2:last');   
   if (last_chekbox2.is(':checked')) {
      $('.checkbox2').prop('checked', false);
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerRace1}" th:value="1" th:text="borrower1" class="checkbox1" /> A
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerRace1}" th:value="2" th:text="borrower2" class="checkbox1" /> B
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerRace1}" th:value="3" th:text="borrower3" class="checkbox1" /> C
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerRace1}" th:value="4" th:text="borrower4" class="checkbox1" /> D
  </label>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerEthnicity1}" th:value="1" th:text="Ethnicity1" class="checkbox2" /> E
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerEthnicity2}" th:value="2" th:text="Ethnicity2" class="checkbox2" /> F
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerEthnicity3}" th:value="3" th:text="Ethnicity3" class="checkbox2" /> G
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{borrowerEthnicity4}" th:value="4" th:text="Ethnicity4" class="checkbox2" /> H
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @Apurba, It seems that the requirement is similar of using [radio buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio). I have updated the answer. It will be better to if you can make the requirement more clear.

Comment: User can select A,B,C checkbox at a same time but when he checks D all the above selected checkboxes should get unselected. Similarly for E,F,G and H. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: @Apurba, I have updated the answer according to your requirement. If the answer helped you please accept it.

Comment: I have some modification in my requirements. The code you have written is for last checkbox what if on select of second last checkbox all the selected options should get unselected. Could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('checkbox1').on('click'function(){
$('checkbox').attr('checked',false)
$(this).attr('checked',true)
})
```

try something like this

Comment: try prop instead of attr